# How to rename a file before insert to a path Java?

Tags: java, file

I need to insert a file to a path. However, the file name need to change to a specific name before inserted.

How can I change the name of the file **before** insert to path? As many resources online only able to change the file name after inserted. [Online Resource for rename file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-to-rename-a-file/)

**My code currently**

```
String localPath = "c://Users/foody/Documents/write_file_local/";

String finalPath = localPath + file.getOriginalFilename();

File uploadPath = new File(finalPath);
if (!uploadPath.getParentFile().exists()) {
    uploadPath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}

//I think need to rename the file here before insert to path

byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
Path path = Paths.get(finalPath);
Files.write(path, bytes);
```

Comment: How about reading the javadocs for File::renameTo - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

Comment: Just change `finalPath` to whatever you want, before you call `Files.write`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this and update your "CustomName_ABC" with your new fileName.

```
String localPath = "c://Users/foody/Documents/write_file_local/";
String finalPath = localPath + "CustomName_ABC";

File uploadPath = new File(finalPath);
if (!uploadPath.getParentFile().exists()) {
    uploadPath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
Files.copy(file.toPath(), uploadPath.toPath());
```

You can copy your old file to a new filePath (directory) by using **Files.copy()** method. It will take two parameters:

1. Old file path
2. New file path